# PowerShell - Execute PowerShell Script on the C: drive of a remote server

Tags: powershell

PowerShell Version 5 build 10586

I am using the following code to remote connect to a server from my local PC

```
$cimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName "SERVERNAME.DOMAIN.COM"


     Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVERNAME -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem “C:\Temp\ps”}

     Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVERNAME -FilePath "\\SERVERNAME\c$\Temp\ps\PS_SCRIPT_FILE.ps1"


Remove-CimSession -CimSession $cimSession
```

The first command is able to run successfully and sees the PowerShell file on the remote server.

The second command fails with an error:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot find path '\\SERVERNAME\c$\Temp\ps\PS_SCRIPT_FILE.ps1' because it does not exist.
```

Is there another way to call/run a PowerShell script on the C Drive of a remote server?

- I have granted my account full access to the specified file.
- I have also tried to share the specified folder and given myself Read/Write access to the folder.
- I have changed the file path to the share path and get the same result.
- `Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVERNAME -FilePath "\\SERVERNAME\ps\PS_SCRIPT_FILE.ps1"`

Comment: Note that your `Invoke-Command` commands are not using the `$cimSession` they are using WinRM protocol to invoke the commands, not WSMAN. This is why the first command worked. In your example above you do not even need to establish a CimSession. Either already be running under credentials that can use WinRM; or use the `-Credentials` option to pass credentials if you are not authenticated to the remote server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh849719.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVERNAME -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\Temp\ps\PS_SCRIPT_FILE.ps1" }`

In your existing code the -FilePath parameter is processed on the calling machine. By including that as a parameter within the ScriptBlock it should be processed on the target machine.